# hbase - is there any "explain" keyword?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I'm searching for an **"explain"** keyword in HBase.

(something like the explain keyword from impala http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/impala_hbase.html )

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an "explain" in HBase because it is not RDBMS. It is a key-value store and all of your operations are get (get value given a key), set (set value for a given key), delete (delete given key) and scans (all the table or specific key range) - that's all. No complex logic, no complex joins that would require explaining - all the operations are simple. Here is a basic guide to HBase: http://hbase.apache.org/book.html, get familiar with first chapters.

In case you need to get the table structure, you can use "describe" command in HBase shell.

Comment: OK, than how can I found out if a filter is doing a full-scan on a field that is not a key?

Comment: If you need to filter data in HBase, you will always end up with full scan. You can avoid it only by filtering on the prefix of the table key, this way only related regions would be scanned. Also you can reduce the amount of data scanned by using SingleColumnValueFilter class, which will allow you to reduce the full scan to the affected column family (column families are stored as separate files in HBase). Another option would be to create a secondary index, you can find the description in the guide I linked (be aware that it would require manual application side logic to use it)

Answer (score 1):

There is no explain as you can add the column on the fly(flexible schema).

but we are having describe command so you will get the description table with family (Not the columns)